# Remove Brackets from Python List for an SQL query

Tags: python, pandas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python challenging string encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770560/python-challenging-string-encoding)

I am trying to put a list of tickers into a SQL query.  I am new to Python.

cus is a list set up as ['x', 'y', ..., 'a']

```
test = psql.frame_query(
    "select * from dataBase where cus IN (%r)", con = db) % cus
```

I tried this and it failed.

My next attempt was to try and remove the brackets and then paste the list in.  How do I remove the brackets so that I get:

```
cus2 = 'x', 'y', ..., 'a'
```

I was going to do:

```
str = "select * from dataBase where cus IN (%r)" % cus2
test2 = psql.frame_query(str, con = db)
```

Or is there another way I should be attempting this?

Thank you.

Comment: To summarize: Do not use string interpolation (`%`) to include values in a SQL query. Use SQL parameters instead; `pandas.io.sql` supports parameters directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With SQL, you really want to avoid just inserting your value into the query. You normally leave that to the database adapter, which has specialized knowledge about how to avoid creating dangerous SQL from your values (SQL quotation escaping, a.k.a. SQL injection attacks).

Unfortunately, the [`pandas.io.sql` module](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/sql.py) has only half-heartedly implemented parameter support.

Instead of using `frame_query`, just use [`DataFrame.from_records()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) directly.

First, generate the SQL query with parameters. The format of the SQL parameters differs from database adapter to database adapter, since the [Python DB API standard](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) allows for a few variants. I'll assume you are using MySQL here, which uses `%s` for positional parameters, echoing Python's syntax:

```
sql = "select * from dataBase where cus IN ({0})".format(', '.join(['%s'] * len(cus2)))
```

That creates enough parameters for each of the values in `cus2`. Then query the database:

```
cur = psql.execute(sql, con, params=cus2)
rows = cur.fetchall()
columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cur.description]
cur.close()

result = DataFrame.from_records(rows, columns=columns, coerce_float=True)
```

Since you appear to be using the [`Sybase` module](http://python-sybase.sourceforge.net/) module for your connection, you'll have to adjust this for the (somewhat non-standard) SQL parameter syntax that library uses. It *only* accepts named parameters, which use the form `@name`:

```
params = dict(('@param{0}'.format(i), v) for i, v in enumerate(cus2))
sql = "select * from dataBase where cus IN ({0})".format(
    ', '.join(sorted(params.keys())))

cur = psql.execute(sql, con, params=params)
rows = cur.fetchall()
columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cur.description]
cur.close()

result = DataFrame.from_records(rows, columns=columns, coerce_float=True)
```

Comment: One follow-up:  for the cur = psql.execute(sql, con, params=cus2) line, I am getting an error that says:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

currently the list is set up ['x', 'y', ... ]

Comment: @user1911092: what database are you connecting to?

Comment: A database that I have here at school

If I remove the params piece and just enter a string with the cus written out - the test works

Comment: and what library is used to connect to sybase?

Comment: I use the pandas.io.sql at this point.  I am not sure if I am answering your question though.

Comment: @user1911092: The `con` object is a database connection. What created that connection? You used a python module for that, correct?

Comment: yes - I used con = Sybase.connect(dataBase, Username, Password)

Comment: @user1911092: Okay, that library is a little more finicky (a technical term) about SQL parameters. Updated the answer to work with its idea of parameter handling.